# How to change default path of http-server from public to something else?

Tags: npm, httpserver

In npmjs website (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) the information given is:

command:

```
http-server [path] [options]
```

[path] defaults to ./public if the folder exists, and ./ otherwise.

But what if I have a public folder but the index.html I want to execute is in not the one in public folder but in the master folder itself? There must be a way to change the path but not information seems to be given.

The reason I want to do this is that I only update public folder when I am happy with the current code. While testing my 'main' index.html is in the master folder which contains the public folder.

Comment: Did you try `http-server ./master`?

Comment: So if my master folder is named as "C:\Users\s\Desktop\hh" then how exactly do I write ./master? Is it dimply ./C:\Users\s\Desktop\hh ? Because that doesn't work.

Comment: Use [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module to build the proper path to your desired folder.